# DynDNS CNAME Best practice

Tags: dns, bind, dynamic-dns

I have a DynDNS account  with `sub.somedyndomain.com`.
In an ideal world I would have `sub.example.com` (where I run `example.com`) functioning the same way as a dyndns, I have a BIND server running on a VPS, but setting up a dyndns server seams more complicated than necessary.

Is there anything against pointing `sub.example.com` to `sub.somedyndomain.com` using a `CNAME`and being done with it?
Performance wise, best practice etc etc?

EDIT: This is for the purposes of accessing a NAS server and web facing RPi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you mention your bind server, but your CNAME solution should work fine. It would be a bit slower (extra lookup) but it should not be problematically so.

Comment: I mention it because the alternative is to run a dyndns server with that bind server.

Comment: What do you mean by run a dyndns server? I understand dyndns to be a service, as opposed to running a dynamic DNS server. The way I did it was to use prodns with a backend database and have a php web page which, when hit with appropriate credentials updated the database record feeding the DNS server with the IP client IP address reported by PHP. I then just use curl or wget from crontab on the client device.

Comment: AFAIK as long as this `service` is accepting requests from a `client` it is considered a `server`. It would be some python script that when accessed would update the DNS records.

Comment: Correct. What throws me is you use of "dyndns" which I understand to be a service run by a particular company.

Comment: ah ok , my bad, I meant my own dynamic dns service